# Best way to implement dropdown with search\Typo with Angular JS version 1.2.2

Tags: angularjs

Best way to implement dropdown with search\Typo with Angular JS version 1.2.2

(application with Asp.net backend, Angular JS front end without using boot strap)

Answer (score 0):

You can use older version of typeahead from `AngularStrap`.

Look at [here](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads) for more info.

Sample code:

```
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> State</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedState" bs-options="state for state in states" placeholder="Enter state" bs-typeahead>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Icon</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedIcon" data-min-length="0" data-html="1" data-auto-select="true" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="icon as icon.label for icon in icons"     placeholder="Enter icon" bs-typeahead>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <!-- Using an async data provider -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Address <small>(async via maps.googleapis.com)</small></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="selectedAddress" data-animation="am-flip-x" bs-options="address.formatted_address as address.formatted_address for address in getAddress($viewValue)"     placeholder="Enter address" bs-typeahead>
  </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.selectedState = "";
$scope.states = ["Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Dakota","North Carolina","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"];

$scope.selectedIcon = "";
$scope.icons = "[{"value":"Gear","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-gear\"></i> Gear"},{"value":"Globe","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-globe\"></i> Globe"},{"value":"Heart","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-heart\"></i> Heart"},{"value":"Camera","label":"<i class=\"fa fa-camera\"></i> Camera"}]";

$scope.selectedAddress = "";
```

Now these arrays can come from server. Take a look at options section.